# I want to add hyperlink of my failed screen shot in my Testng Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have tried below Code in my `Onfailure` method

```
Reporter.log("Screenshot can be found : <a target=\"_blank\" href="+imagePath+">Screenshot</a>");
```

AND another attempt

```
Reporter.log("<a target=\"_blank\" href="+imagePath+">Screenshot</a>");
```

None of them Worked Can anyone help me??

Comment: What's the result (wrong output, exception, blank page) and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to @Override the TestNg method

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult failingTest) {
    try {
           //write your code here
}
```

Below syntax are working for me

```
Reporter.log("<a href=\"" + snapfile + "\"><p align=\"left\">Add New PR screenshot at " + subDir + "</p>");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Yes, I have done Orerride part but still was not able to get the hyperlink.It is printing path of the file.What are the snapfile and sudDir Variables

Comment: snapshot is the file name of my snapshot and sudDir are the folder name which carry my snapshots.. it's on depend on you how you want to custamize it

Comment: Oh yes! one important part.. please put your snapshot folder inside the test-output folder only ;) ..

Comment: You can see how it is displayed in my Report                                                               Screenshot can be found : <a target="_blank" href=C:\Ravi\workspace\FoxWebAutomationTestNGProject/Screenshots/RepurchaseTest/repurchaseReqAUS497.jpg>Screenshot</a>